Database of nouns linked to pictures
Are there any large databases of Chinese noun words, each with a corresponding picture of what the thing looks like? The closest resource found so far are 'visual dictionary' books.

For this task, I sometimes check out lists of emojis in Chinese, such as at EmojiAll:




Good idea, looks like there are 3700+ emojis with corresponding words there!

Maybe put the word in 百度?百度 is a big database!
Go to: https://www.baidu.com
enter your word + 翻译成中文: eggplant翻译成中文 in the search box
eggplant翻译成中文: 茄子
Then put the result (茄子) in https://image.baidu.com/
Of course, there are many images for 1 word.
"joy" and "anger" are nouns, but I suspect there is no picture available for them!
Using web-scraping you could build your own database, if you know how to web-scrape and MySQL!

Thanks, but I was after an existing database of word-image pairs, not how to look up a picture for a corresponding word.

I would go to a services like anki, many people like to pair  representative image to a vocab and that makes many easily strippable lists :)
